# how to pass array from WinForm to WebService

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

How to pass array from WinForm to WebService?

Can I get any C# sample?

Comment: Array can be sent just as is. What is your trial and what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Can you post what you have attempted.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, simply **add a Web Reference or a Service Reference** to your WinForm project and it will create the service proxy for you. This assumes that your WebService is exposing a WSDL file that describes the methods and parameters used.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question, and it would depend entirely on the type of web service you are looking for.  Here are some instructions on how to add a Web Service reference:

[Add a link to a web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)

Once added, you can call whatever method requires an array and pass in the array through the parameters.  A sample instantiation and method call for a web service might look like this:

```
MyWebService myWebServiceInstance = new MyWebService(url);
string[] params = new string[2];
myWebServiceInstance.CallArrayMethod(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the web service is SOAP based, it should have a WSDL. If so, simply import a service reference to the WSDL and it will set up the proxy for you. Then you create an array and pass it to the method in question.

If you are talking REST based services, I would look at the RestBucks implementation on CodePlex (http://restbucks.codeplex.com/). You will want to look at the client side code. It will show you how to add your "array" in the call body, while setting up header information, etc.

Worst case is going down to a lower level and creating your own Request object. Most likely that would be overkill.